# I get error CS7036 and I am clueless on how to solve it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to coding and using it for a school project. I have seen some code learning sessions, but my coding abilities are limited.

What I basically want, is an enemy moving up, stopping at a collider and then moving down and stopping at another ground collider and repeat.
At first, I found a script that, should it be used, the object will move up/down until it meets a collider. This is that particular code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Vector3 movement;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
            moveCharacter(movement);
    }

    void moveCharacter(Vector3 direction)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

I decided to modify it, to satisfy the needs that I mentioned, like this (note that when I tested the above code, it worked normally)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy_Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 0.1f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector3 movement;
    public Collider2D EnemyCollider;
    public Collider2D DirtCollider;
    public Collider2D CeilingCollider;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 1f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        if (EnemyCollider.IsTouching(DirtCollider))
        {
            moveCharacterUp();
        }

        if (EnemyCollider.IsTouching(CeilingCollider))
        {
            moveCharacterDown();
        }
    }
    void moveCharacterUp(Vector3 direction)
    {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(movement.x + transform.position.x, movement.y + transform.position.y, movement.z + transform.position.z);
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (offset * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    void moveCharacterDown(Vector3 direction)
    {
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3(movement.x + transform.position.x, movement.y + transform.position.y, movement.z + transform.position.z);
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position - (offset * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following message

> Assets\Enemy_Movement.cs(32,13): error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'direction' of 'Enemy_Movement.moveCharacterDown(Vector3)'

I know that I might have done an idiotic mistake, but unfortunately, I have searched everywhere but I could not find a proper solution. (And yea, it looks hideous, but it is my first project).
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `moveCharacterDown` method takes a `Vector3` argument, but you're trying to call it without arguments, hence the error. Having said that, after reading through the code, this argument is not used, so the easiest solution would be to remove it:

```
void moveCharacterUp() // Here
{
    Vector3 offset = new Vector3(movement.x + transform.position.x, movement.y + transform.position.y, movement.z + transform.position.z);
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (offset * speed * Time.deltaTime));
}

void moveCharacterDown() // And here
{
    Vector3 offset = new Vector3(movement.x + transform.position.x, movement.y + transform.position.y, movement.z + transform.position.z);
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position - (offset * speed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you call the `moveCharacterUp` and `moveCharacterDown` methods. Both methods expect a `Vector3` as a parameter, but you use them without a parameter.

Since you don't seem to use the direction parameter in the methods anyway, remove them and it should fix the problem.